# How to speed up iterating through an array / matrix? Tried both pandas and numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I would like to do some feature enrichment through a large 2 dimensional array (15,100m).

Working on a sample set with 100'000 records showed that I need to get this faster.

**Edit** (data model info)

To simplify, let's say we have only two relevant columns:

- IP (identifier)
- Unix (timestamp in seconds since 1970)

I would like to add a 3rd column, counting how many times this IP has shown up in the past 12 hours.

**End edit**

My first attempt was using pandas, because it was comfortable working with named dimensions, but too slow:

```
for index,row in tqdm_notebook(myData.iterrows(),desc='iterrows'):
# how many times was the IP address (and specific device) around in the prior 5h?
    hours = 12
    seen = myData[(myData['ip']==row['ip'])
                 &(myData['device']==row['device'])
                 &(myData['os']==row['os'])
                 &(myData['unix']<row['unix'])
                 &(myData['unix']>(row['unix']-(60*60*hours)))].shape[0]
    ip_seen = myData[(myData['ip']==row['ip'])
                 &(myData['unix']<row['unix'])
                 &(myData['unix']>(row['unix']-(60*60*hours)))].shape[0]
    myData.loc[index,'seen'] = seen
    myData.loc[index,'ip_seen'] = ip_seen
```

Then I switched to numpy arrays and hoped for a better result, but it is still too slow to run against the full dataset:

```
# speed test numpy arrays
for i in np.arange(myArray.shape[0]):
    hours = 12
    ip,device,os,ts = myArray[i,[0,3,4,12]]
    ip_seen = myArray[(np.where((myArray[:,0]==ip) 
                            & (myArray[:,12]<ts)
                            & (myArray[:,12]>(ts-60*60*hours) )))].shape[0]
    device_seen = myArray[(np.where((myArray[:,0]==ip) 
                            & (myArray[:,2] == device)
                            & (myArray[:,3] == os)
                            & (myArray[:,12]<ts)
                            & (myArray[:,12]>(ts-60*60*hours) )))].shape[0]
    myArray[i,13]=ip_seen
    myArray[i,14]=device_seen
```

My next idea would be to iterate only once, and maintain a growing dictionary of the current count, instead of looking backwards in every iteration.

But that would have some other drawbacks (e.g. how to keep track when to reduce count for observations falling out of the 12h window).

How would you approach this problem?

Could it be even an option to use low level Tensorflow functions to involve a GPU?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your data and the expected output for the sample?

Comment: Iterating over the rows will be slow, no matter which library you use, in python. Which format is your database? If your database is huge, pandas might not be the best option to manipulate it. Why not just use SQL?

Comment: @jdehesa, see updated post above for data model (simplified to illustrate the idea).

Comment: @Imanol, DB is irrelevant, now it all happens in memory and for the full data set it could also be run in batches if too large. SQL is not not designed for 'rolling' updates with frequent re-fetches. I think this would slow it down even more, as it would re-read from disk all the time.

Comment: If you set the time as index, you can use `DataFrame.rolling`. Please provide some sample data, so we can test some possible solutions

Comment: @Maarten, rolling assumes "Each window will be a fixed size." which is not true. It is basically a log file where every occurrence of an IP address is stored with a timestamp. So the length of the window would be dynamic if looking back a time range.

Comment: Do you have many multiple entries from ip, device,os and so on? If so, exploiting that and using a compiler/jit compiler can improve the speed by orders of magnitudes... Such multiple lookups can always be heavily optimized with sorting beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in the comment to @jdehesa, I took another approach which allows me to only iterate once through the entire dataset and pull the (decaying) weight from an index.

```
decay_window = 60*60*12 # every 12
decay = 0.5 # fall by 50% every window
ip_idx = pd.DataFrame(myData.ip.unique())
ip_idx['ts_seen'] = 0
ip_idx['ip_seen'] = 0
ip_idx.columns = ['ip','ts_seen','ip_seen']
ip_idx.set_index('ip',inplace=True)

for index, row in myData.iterrows(): # all
    # How often was this IP seen?
    prior_ip_seen = ip_idx.loc[(row['ip'],'ip_seen')]
    prior_ts_seen = ip_idx.loc[(row['ip'],'ts_seen')]
    delay_since_count = row['unix']-ip_idx.loc[(row['ip'],'ts_seen')]
    new_ip_seen = prior_ip_seen*decay**(delay_since_count/decay_window)+1
    ip_idx.loc[(row['ip'],'ip_seen')] = new_ip_seen
    ip_idx.loc[(row['ip'],'ts_seen')] = row['unix']
    myData.iloc[index,14] = new_ip_seen-1
```

That way the result is not the fixed time window as requested initially, but prior observations "fade out" over time, giving frequent recent observations a higher weight.

This feature carries more information than the simplified (and turned out more expensive) approach initially planned.

Thanks for your input!

**Edit**

In the meantime I switched to numpy arrays for the same operation, which now only takes a fraction of the time (loop with 200m updates in <2h).

Just in case somebody looks for a starting point:

```
%%time
import sys
## temporary lookup
ip_seen_ts = [0]*365000
ip_seen_count = [0]*365000
cnt = 0
window = 60*60*12 # 12h
decay = 0.5
counter = 0
chunksize = 10000000
store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')
t = time.process_time()
try:
    store.remove('myCount')
except:
    print("myData not present.")
for myHdfData in store.select_as_multiple(['myData','myFeatures'],columns=['ip','unix','ip_seen'],chunksize=chunksize):
    print(counter, time.process_time() - t)
    #display(myHdfData.head(5))
    counter+=chunksize
    t = time.process_time()
    sys.stdout.flush()
    keep_index = myHdfData.index.values
    myArray = myHdfData.as_matrix()
    for row in myArray[:,:]:
        #for row in myArray:
        i = (row[0].astype('uint32')) # IP as identifier
        u = (row[1].astype('uint32')) # timestamp
        try:
            delay = u - ip_seen_ts[i]
        except:
            delay = 0
        ip_seen_ts[i] = u
        try:
            ip_seen_count[i] = ip_seen_count[i]*decay**(delay/window)+1
        except:
            ip_seen_count[i] = 1
        row[3] = np.tanh(ip_seen_count[i]-1) # tanh to normalize between 0 and 1
    myArrayAsDF = pd.DataFrame(myArray,columns=['c_ip','c_unix','c_ip2','ip_seen'])
    myArrayAsDF.set_index(keep_index,inplace=True)
    store.append('myCount',myArrayAsDF)
store.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to speed up things is *not* looping. In your case you can try using [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with a window of the time span that you want, using the Unix timestamp as a datetime index (assuming that records are sorted by timestamp, otherwise you would need to sort first). This should work fine for the `ip_seen`:

```
ip = myData['ip']
ip.index = pd.to_datetime(myData['unix'], unit='s')
myData['ip_seen'] = ip.rolling('5h')
    .agg(lambda w: np.count_nonzero(w[:-1] == w[-1]))
    .values.astype(np.int32)
```

However, when the aggregation involves multiple columns, like in the `seen` column, it gets more complicated. Currently (see [Pandas issue #15095](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15095)) rolling functions do not support aggregations spanning two dimensions. A workaround could be merging the columns of interest into a single new series, for example a tuple (which may work better if values are numbers) or a string (which may be better is values are already strings). For example:

```
criteria = myData['ip'] + '|' + myData['device'] + '|' + myData['os']
criteria.index = pd.to_datetime(myData['unix'], unit='s')
myData['seen'] = criteria.rolling('5h')
    .agg(lambda w: np.count_nonzero(w[:-1] == w[-1]))
    .values.astype(np.int32)
```

**EDIT**

Apparently [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) only works with numeric types, which leaves as with two options:

1. Manipulate the data to use numeric types. For the IP this is easy, since it actually represents a 32 bit number (or 64 if IPv6 I guess). For device and OS, assuming they are strings now, it get's more complicated, you would have to map each possible value to an integer and the merge it with the IP in a long value, e.g. putting these in the higher bits or something like that (maybe even impossible with IPv6, since the biggest integers NumPy supports right now are 64 bits).
2. Roll over the index of `myData` (which should now be *not* datetime, because `rolling` cannot work with that either) and use the index window to get the necessary data and operate:

   ```
   # Use sequential integer index
   idx_orig = myData.index
   myData.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
   # Index to roll
   idx = pd.Series(myData.index)
   idx.index = pd.to_datetime(myData['unix'], unit='s')
   # Roll aggregation function
   def agg_seen(w, data, fields):
       # Use slice for faster data frame slicing
       slc = slice(int(w[0]), int(w[-2])) if len(w) > 1 else []
       match = data.loc[slc, fields] == data.loc[int(w[-1]), fields]
       return np.count_nonzero(np.all(match, axis=1))
   # Do rolling
   myData['ip_seen'] = idx.rolling('5h') \
       .agg(lambda w: agg_seen(w, myData, ['ip'])) \
       .values.astype(np.int32)
   myData['ip'] = idx.rolling('5h') \
       .agg(lambda w: agg_seen(w, myData, ['ip', 'device', 'os'])) \
       .values.astype(np.int32)
   # Put index back
   myData.index = idx_orig
   ```

   This is not how `rolling` is meant to be used, though, and I'm not sure if this gives much better performance than just looping.

Comment: Great, I wasn't aware rolling can handle variable time windows. Will give it a try and revert back. Thanks!

Comment: @szeta I'm noting that `rolling` doesn't work as it is with strings, it seems to skip every non-numeric value, I'm looking into an alternative path.

Comment: @szeta I've added something using `rolling` that works with strings, although it seems quite slow, not sure if it's any better than your original code...

Comment: @szeta Btw, are you looking for pattern repetitions in the time window _before_ the current record or including it? (that is, should all results be at least 1, because of counting the current row?)

Comment: I have been playing with the rolling function but could not achieve any significant improvement. After our discussions I realized it may be easier (and even better) instead of having a rolling window of counts, build up a half-life-decay for counts between observations. Didn't have time to code yet, but will share here once I have something useful.